# Clear contents of two sheets from the macro file

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button_Click()

    With Thiswoorkbook.sheets("abc")
      .Rows("2:"&.Rows.count).ClearContents
    End with

    with Thiswoorkbook.sheets("xyz")
      .Rows("1:"&.Rows.count).ClearContents
    End with

end sub
```

i am using the above mentioned codes but i need to click twice clear the contents is there any way to fix the code to do it in single click

Comment: can you elaborate on this a little more: *but i need to click twice clear the contents*? Also, it's not advisable to take actions against **entire rows** but only where there *is actually data*. Adjusting for that may help.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. Could you give more information?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you have provided, it seems that you may have assigned the macro to a shape, then you have to double click the shape to get it to run. An ActiveX control button will run with a single click. See how to put an ActiveX control button into your spreadsheet at the linked documentation for Microsoft Office. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-Form-or-a-Control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283